# How to change border color in div ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web development, i have learned basics of Java, JSP, HTML, JS, CSS, JQ. I am stuck at a point in which I am trying to change the border color of a div when mouse hover event occurs, but I am failing in doing so. Below is the related code, please point out the mistakes and point me in a better directions. Thanks alot in advance.

P.S: I have tried almost every stackoverflows questions/answers but I still failed to accomplished it. I thought it would be better if I post my own question with code to get suggestions for future aswell. Thanks is advance.

```
<div id="navBar" style="height: 50px; width: 480px;">
            <div id="homeButton" style="float: left; color: #73C20E; position:relative; width: 160px; height: 50px; border-top: 4px solid #73C20E;">
                <p>Home</p>
            </div>
            <div id="siteAdminButton" style="float: left; color: #73C20E;  position: relative; width: 160px; height: 50px; border-top: 4px solid #1C1C1C;" >
                <p>Site Administration</p>
            </div>
            <div id="contactButton" style="float: left; color: #73C20E;  width: 160px; height: 50px; border-top: 4px solid #1C1C1C;">
                <p>Contact Us</p>
            </div>                    
</div>
```

Heres JS:

```
$("document").ready(function (){
    $("#homeButton").mouseenter(function (){
        $(this).addClass("mouseOverNav");
    }).mouseleave(function (){
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOverNav");
    });  

    $("#siteAdminButton").mouseenter(function (){
        $(this).addClass("mouseOverNav");
    }).mouseleave(function (){
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOverNav");
    });

    $("#contactButton").mouseenter(function (){
        $(this).addClass("mouseOverNav");
    }).mouseleave(function (){
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOverNav");
    });
});
```

and here is css:

```
.mouseOverNav {
   cursor: pointer;   
   border-color: #73C20E;
}
```

Summary: I have created 3 divs with borders, 2 of which have the same border color as background, I want to change border color to my theme whenever mouse hovers, and change it back to the background color when mouse leaves and make the cursor a Pointer.

So far: Pointer Cursor is working but its not changing the border color. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shorten your selectors to:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#homeButton, #siteAdminButton, #contactButton").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).addClass("mouseOverNav");
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOverNav");
    });
});
```

You've set inline style `border-top: 4px solid #1C1C1C;` in your HTML, so you need to use `border-top` style for `.mouseOverNav` in your external css as well.

You also need to apply `!important` property to override the existing style since inline style take precedence over external style:

```
.mouseOverNav {
   cursor: pointer;   
   border-top: 4px solid #73C20E !important;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgY3Y/)**

---

Edit: Although above suggestion works, but actually you should avoid to use `!important` when unnecessary, from MDN **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**:

> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
>   debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets.

In your case, you can move all the inline styles to external css, like this:

```
#homeButton, #siteAdminButton, #contactButton {
    float: left;
    color: #73C20E;
    position:relative;
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 4px solid #73C20E;
}
#siteAdminButton, #contactButton {
    border-top: 4px solid #1C1C1C;
}

#navBar .mouseOverNav {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 4px solid #73C20E;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgY3Y/1/)**

Also, you can achieve above task using poor CSS by applying **[:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover)** selector:

```
#homeButton:hover, #siteAdminButton:hover, #contactButton:hover{
   cursor: pointer;   
   border-top: 4px solid #73C20E;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgY3Y/2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Thanks for explaining the !important property as well. :)

Comment: Hey Felix thanks for updating thats really helpful, so what i learned here is that: If I use an inline property and want to edit it on events through CSS,then i have to use !important property. But, if I do it all in external CSS, it will be modified through it aswell. Am I right. ?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. If you use external CSS the correct way, there's no need to use `!important` at all.

Answer (score 4):

**YOU CAN SIMPLY ACHIEVE THIS USING CSS `:hover`. NO NEED TO USE JAVASCRIPT OR JQUERY**

In css, you can use like this

```
#homeButton:hover, #siteAdminButton:hover, #contactButton:hover{
   cursor: pointer;   
   border-color: #73C20E !important;
}
```

**HERE IS THE FIDDLE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/yn4dg/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be done using CSS. No need to use JS at all.

```
#navBar > div:hover{
   cursor: pointer;   
   border-color: #73C20E!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please elaborate " #id > element:event " in term of CSS that you have used here.

Comment: you are using all your headers within `#navBar`. So first select the `#navBar` and then your header content within `div` so select it as a second selector like `#navBar > div`. you need the action in mouse over. So, you need to use hover event for the selected DOM `#navBar > div`

Comment: #navBar selects navBar element, and '> div' selects all children divs of #navBar and :hover is the pseudo selector that applies the defines styles on hover of the mouse to the selected elements.

Comment: @Veera you by the requirement, you should use `border-top` property. unless, it will take is as a whole `div's` border.

Comment: @CJRamki no need. Since the OP has defined only the border-top inline,  when you change border-color, it affects only the top border. The other borders doesn't defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

change your css

```
.mouseOverNav {
   cursor: pointer;   
   border-top: 4px solid #73C20E !important;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8sns6/3/

Also I will suggest you to use `hover` function rather of mouse enter and leave

```
$("document").ready(function (){
    $("#homeButton").hover(function (){
        $(this).addClass("mouseOverNav");
    },function (){
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOverNav");
    });  

    $("#siteAdminButton").hover(function (){
        $(this).addClass("mouseOverNav");
    }, function (){
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOverNav");
    });

    $("#contactButton").hover(function (){
        $(this).addClass("mouseOverNav");
    }, function (){
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOverNav");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8sns6/5/

Comment: Thanks it does creates border with defined color and works but what I am looking for here is:
border-top: 4px solid #73C20E;

Comment: since I have a border-top with color same as background, I only need to change the color, 
i.e. border-top-color: #73C20E;

Answer (score 0):

Check this fidde working with your example
http://jsfiddle.net/g6Jf2/

```
.mouseOverNav {
   cursor: pointer;   
   border: 1px solid #73C20E;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I am looking for, since I have a border already created. border-top: 4px solid #1C1C1C; I only want to change the color of the border i.e. border-top-color: #73C20E;

Comment: check updated jsfiddle at "http://jsfiddle.net/g6Jf2/2/" here top border color is getting updated.